# Thymeleaf insert fragment with additional attributes

Tags: thymeleaf

Let us suppose to insert a fragment with Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:insert="templates/fragment.html"> This will be discarded in favour of fragment</div>
```

Now, I want additionally put

```
style="......"
```

In the first tag of the fragment. Is it possible? If yes, can I add an attribute in a specific point within the fragment? In other words is there a way to parametrically add fragments with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the fragment with

```
<div th:insert="templates/fragment.html :: fragName(parameter)">
```

and then with the fragment I use

```
th:fragment="fragmName(parameter)"
```

and

```
th:attr="style=${parameter}"
```